# Book recommendation: Does anybody know a book adopting a more intuitive approach to the topic of Crystal Vibrations (phonons) than the Book by Kittel?

Tags: solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, crystals, vibrations, phonons

I have tried Simon's 'Oxford Solid State basics' and Kittel 8th edition but I am not impressed by both  (I mean the content covered through Chapters 4 and 5 in Kittel)

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide more detail on what *exactly* you found insufficient in the two books you have tried? Thanks!

Comment: David tong's lecture notes are great for intuition.

Comment: Many people find Kittel's treatment of phonons to be among the best parts of his book.

Comment: @Buzz Kittel is definitely not that terrible but I felt I still need to read more ;the picture did not seem complete to me

Comment: @Jonas Simon is insufficient in many ways. It comes to discuss crystal vibrations before even discussing the basics of crystal structure (Brillouin zones, Reciprocal lattice,....etc).Moreover, the treatment itself is inadequate .Simon is a great text in terms of problem solving (because it has nice problems as well as an available solutions manual).However, you should really read the topic somewhere else before solving these .Kittel is great but I felt the need to read more particularly with the topic of Crystal Vibrations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you would or wouldn't find intuitive, so I'll just say which book I like best: J.M. Ziman's *Electrons and Phonons: The Theory of Transport Phenomena in Solids* https://global.oup.com/academic/product/electrons-and-phonons-9780198507796?cc=us&lang=en&

A lot of the book probably isn't relevant to you (and it's super old-school --- one of the first books on the subject), but the first chapter is my favorite explanation of phonons. FWIW, Ziman's derivation is a little unusual (quantum from the start).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give an explanation but can point to some other sources. Hook and Hall have a decent book on Solid State Physics, here is the link
https://www.wiley.com/en-gb/Solid+State+Physics%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471928058 .

There are also numerous sets of lecture notes that come up when you google 'Solid state physics pdf'. Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Is this available anywhere as a pdf ? I could not find it unlike Kittel, Ashcroft and Simon which were relatively easy to obtain.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a PDF copy freely floating around sorry